# Checking for value in session BEFORE opening specific JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, controller

I want to check if a value in the session in null or not before opening a specific JSP page (authentification.jsp wich is mapped authentification.html and controlled by AuthentificationController.java)
If that value is null I want the user to be redirected to an other page, else I want him to stay in that that page 
I can't find a solution because in the controller I only have formBackingObject or onSubmit methods

Comment: If we are to assume you are storing a variable in the Session object, then in the AuthentificationController class you should be checking with a conditional statement like: String myvariable = session.getAttribute("myvariable"); if(myvariable == null){...}else{...} If I am missing the point of your question then we need to see more code to fully understand your query.

Comment: If this is global functionality put it in a `HandlerInterceptor` or servlet `Filter`. That way you only need to implement it once.

Comment: @M.Deinum How do I use the HandlerInterceptor for one and only URL??

Comment: If it is only one, build it in your controller.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use Spring 3.x, but on the other hand it looks like you use the old Spring 2.0 [`(Simple)FormController`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/SimpleFormController.html).

Really **first learn how to use Spring 3.x Annotation Based Controller** and Controller Methods. (For example https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

Back to you problem:

To obtain a the `HttpSession` in a  Spring 3.x Annotation Based Controller Method, simply add a Attribute of type `HttpSession` to the controller method:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public ModelAndView example(@RequestParam("name") String whatEver, ..., HttpSession session) {

        if (session.getAttribute("theVarialbe") != null) {
           return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("somePage.html", true));
        } else {           
           Model model = new Model();
           return new ModelAndView("myJsp", model);        
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand how to use that code and I don't think that solves the problem. I want to check the content of the session before opening a specific URL and choose what to do later. And I can't use the annotations, I must use XML

Comment: you CAN NOT check the session context before some Request is send to the server, because the Session exists only in the server, and it is associated with the HttpServletRequest